# Spring Basic Authentication of cxf Endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf, apache-camel

I have a **camel-config.xml** from Apache Camel Bundle in the example folder(example is camel-example-cxf-proxy). The config file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- START SNIPPET: e1 -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

  <!-- spring property placeholder, ignore resource not found as the file resource is for unit testing -->
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:incident.properties,file:target/custom.properties"
                                ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>

  <!-- Use a bean to start and stop the real web service (is not Camel specific) -->
  <!-- In a real use-case the real web service would be probably located on another server
       but we simulate this in the same JVM -->
  <bean id="realWebService" class="org.apache.camel.example.cxf.proxy.RealWebServiceBean"
        init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <!-- url of the real web service we have proxied -->
    <property name="url" value="http://localhost:${real.port}/real-webservice"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- bean that enriches the SOAP request -->
  <bean id="enrichBean" class="org.apache.camel.example.cxf.proxy.EnrichBean"/>

  <!-- this is the CXF web service we use as the front end -->
  <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="reportIncident"
                   address="http://localhost:${proxy.port}/camel-example-cxf-proxy/webservices/incident"
                   endpointName="s:ReportIncidentEndpoint"
                   serviceName="s:ReportIncidentEndpointService"
                   wsdlURL="etc/report_incident.wsdl"
                   xmlns:s="http://reportincident.example.camel.apache.org"/>

  <!-- this is the Camel route which proxies the real web service and forwards SOAP requests to it -->
  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <!-- property which contains port number -->
    <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:incident.properties,file:target/custom.properties"/>

    <endpoint id="callRealWebService" uri="http://localhost:${real.port}/real-webservice?throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>

    <route>
      <!-- CXF consumer using MESSAGE format -->
      <from uri="cxf:bean:reportIncident?dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
      <!-- log input received -->
      <to uri="log:input"/>
      <!-- enrich the input by ensure the incidentId parameter is set -->
      <to uri="bean:enrichBean"/>
      <!-- send proxied request to real web service -->
      <to ref="callRealWebService"/>
      <!-- log answer from real web service -->
      <to uri="log:output"/>
    </route>

  </camelContext>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: e1 -->
```

Now i am able to create a proxy service. What i am looking for is, I want to implement Basic authentication to the following section of cofiguration file i.e.,

```
<!-- this is the CXF web service we use as the front end -->
  <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="reportIncident"
                   address="http://localhost:${proxy.port}/camel-example-cxf-proxy/webservices/incident"
                   endpointName="s:ReportIncidentEndpoint"
                   serviceName="s:ReportIncidentEndpointService"
                   wsdlURL="etc/report_incident.wsdl"
                   xmlns:s="http://reportincident.example.camel.apache.org"/>
```

I am not getting, how to do this. Googled this but was not able to find anything concrete.
Looking forward to your solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty support to setup customer [security handler](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/SecuredHelloHandler.java) , you can inject this handler into jetty engine like [this](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jetty-configuration.html).